# Advisable storage medium on image files

Tags: php, image, web, upload

I'm working on a project that has 6000 users. It is a web-based system that processes application forms. Each form submission will contain 4 image files.

I want to know what is the best thing to do to store those image files that is connected to that Form submission.

Is it good to store it in a database or store it in a folder using the hard drive storage?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wow! Guys thank you for all the help! If could only checked those comments :( by the way. Thats it I'll be using filesystem storage rather than blob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing images in folder is better option and store their names/paths in db table. I have personally tried to save images/files in db table and folder both and my experience with the latter one was better. So I suggest it.
And even if images are continuously updated it can be done easily if images are in folders. Just delete the previously existing image and replace it with new one. If you think image names can conflict then you can append or prepend username and timestamp with each image. This will ensure each image has unique name and will be very less likely to conflict.

Answer (score 0):

This is asked quite a lot [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay). So the answer according to most would be file system.

However, if the users continuously update those images, then the database would be a better solution for speed. Also, 24000 images is not much, so DB storage isn't that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the database location reduces the size of database greatly as well updating or replacing the image are much simpler as it is just an file operation instead of massive update/insert/delete in database.

and also refer this it might help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

all the best.

Answer (score 0):

IMO i will store it in a folder and just store the file name instead.  For all the projects I made, I never tried to use blob or the like.  Here is a fair [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717264/should-i-use-mysql-blob-field-type) of it

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting folder (store it in a folder using the hard drive storage). Image store in database has some disadvantages go through 
this link [Disadvantages of storing images in a Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771377/disadvantages-of-storing-images-in-a-database)